# Downloading from Chromium source repository

Tags: git, google-code

I am a newbie I do not know how to download the code from repositories and stuff. I tried tortoise Hg it failed. https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/deps/third_party/openmax/+/refs/heads/master
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The repository you are referencing is not a Subversion repository, it is a [Git](http://git-scm.com/) repository.

As such you'll need Git tools to clone it. The original tool for that is a Linux based command line tool but it sounds like you'd prefer something with a GUI. Fortunately there is a list of GUI Git tools available here: http://git-scm.com/downloads/guis